# Gamepad 'Calibrate' is disabled in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

I have this generic gamepad controller Ipega PG-9068 connected to a Windows 10 PC. The device was detected and functioning normally via Bluetooth. After disconnecting and reconnecting it, the gamepad 'flag' is not applying to the device again.

It is not a device issue. It works normally in another PC.

No driver is provided by the manufacturer. It is plug and play, no driver needed.

So, **although the device gets connected via Bluetooth and recognized**, the calibration button won't be enabled.

[image]

The computer has already been restarted, the Bluetooth device has already been removed and added again. No "update drivers" applies here because it is a generic device that works on any other computer.

Now, how can I get Windows to recognize it as a gamepad again and allow it to be calibrated?

Edit:

- Windows 10 v1809 build 17763.864
- USB 3.0 Bluetooth dongle 4.0
- Only 1 Bluetooth device

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running?  What type of BT adapter are you using?  Do you have multiple BT devices connected to your machine.  Please edit your question to include this vital information.

Comment: Did you try the "Reset to default" button followed by click on OK?

Comment: @harrymc yes I did.

Comment: “USB 3.0 Bluetooth dongle 4.0” - Please be more descriptive.  Is there a reason you are still running 1809?

Comment: If this happened recently and System Restore is enabled, you can rollback the state of Windows to a point in time when the gamepad worked correctly.

Comment: @Ramhound If this is an 1809 issue post it as an answer and you get +150. I have limited bandwidth so I cannot follow every new Windows build.

Comment: @harrymc System restore is disbaled. I wouldn't want to do the system restore only for that.

Comment: No point, as it's too late.

Comment: It's a mistake to disable System Restore, as it is the best method for safely undoing an unknown bad update or manipulation. I suggest doing [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) in order to set all Windows components to a known state.

Comment: @harrymc Well if it was to system restore or to reinstall a newer Windows version I wouldn't have posted this question in the 1st place. In my environment, system restore must be disabled.

Comment: In-place Upgrade is not an new installation. It's basically doing Windows upgrade where everything is conserved. In your case, it will upgrade your Windows 1809 to 1909 (or perhaps 2004 according to whether Microsoft has verified it on your setup). Take backups before starting, the same as before every Windows upgrade.

Comment: @harrymc all the same.

Comment: I think you will nit escape a [Repair Install with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Answer (score -1):

Any time that I had issues with that button it was because i had to force a correct driver to explain to the computer where the throttle/axis where.

Or I had to install a gamepad wrapper.

A program that would trick windows to thinking it was an xbox controller.